# assign ajax variable value to input field

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

```js
<input type="text" id="all_lineitem" name="all_lineitem[]">

function getlineitemid(){
 var a = $('#purchase_req').val();
 $('#hidden_req').val(a);
 var req = $('#hidden_req').val();
 //alert(req);
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo admin_url('PurchaseOrder/getlineitemid/')?>", 
  data: {"req":req}, 
  dataType : 'json',
 
  success: function(data) {
    var lineitemid = data.lineitemid;
    for(var i = 0; i<parseInt(lineitemid.length); i++){
    console.log(lineitemid[i].id);
    $('#lineitemid1').val(lineitemid[i].id);
    var a = lineitemid[i].id;
    $('#all_lineitem').val(a); 
    alert(a);
    }
  }
 }); 
}
```

Value of variable `a` is not assigned to input field. I want to add multiple values to input field.

Comment: i only see 1 input field so I'm not sure how you plan on adding more than 1 value to it other than turning it in to a comma separated string.

Comment: @alex I want to add comma separated string to input field

Comment: but it add only one value to input

Comment: as per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex please specify your input (in this case from the json response) as well as desired output as additions to the above question. please further elucidate why `all_lineitem` is specified as an array `all_lineitem[]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your json data is somewhat like this

```
{"lineitemid":[{"id":1,...},{"id":2,...},...],...}
```

When you loop the data and setting the id to textbox, only the last value will be shown in the textbox. So, you can create an array and store the ids to it. Then simply calling `toString()` method on your array will make the ids comma separated.

```
success: function(data){
    var lineitemid = data.lineitemid;
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<parseInt(lineitemid.length); i++){
        var a = lineitemid[i].id;
        array.push(lineitemid[i].id);
    }
    $('#all_lineitem').val(array.toString()); 
}
```